# Combine result of multiple XPath in YQL queries

Tags: xml, xpath, yql

I was trying to get the stock price and time stamp in the same query so that only one call is made to the server

```
select * 
from html 
where url="http://getquote.icicidirect.com/NewSiteTrading/trading/equity  
 /includes/trading_stock_quote.asp?Symbol=BSES" 
and (
xpath='//table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADE PRICE"]/td[2]/p/text() 
| //table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADED TIME"]/td[5]/p/text()'
```

It gives me following result

```
<results>385.6515:47:38</results>
```

However I wanted to have these result in tag delimitered e.g.

```
<results>
 <price>385.65</price>
 <timestamp>15:47:38<timestamp>
</results>
```

Any way to include these constants ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply create new nodes with XPath, but you can change it the way that it returns the nodes instead of the text-content.

Currently your XPath uses `text()` at the end to only get the text-content inside the table cell. You may adjust this to return the `p` nodes by changing your query slightly:

```
xpath='//table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADE PRICE"]/td[2]/p | //table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADED TIME"]/td[5]/p'
```

This will return two `p` nodes per query, which may help the desired processing of the results.

(By the way, when I checked the URL there were no `p` nodes on the lowest level and thus the query returned no results. You should check if the current HTML of the page still contains the `p` element that you expect.)

Additionally, you may find it useful to use XPath-Axis-Operations to navigate to the desired result instead of using fixed number filters, like this:

```
xpath='//td[p/text()="LAST TRADE PRICE"]/following-sibling::td[2]/p | //td[p/text()="LAST TRADED TIME"]/preceding-sibling::td[1]/p'
```

By filtering sibling-axis, you may jump to a node relative to your current result, so in the example, it finds the `LAST TRADE PRICE` `td` node and moves to the second following sibling `td` node.

The second part navigates to the `td` node with the content `LAST TRADED TIME` and picks up the `td` sibling that preceds.

Using XPath-Axis you will still get a correct result even if there are more rows in the returning webpage - this may come in handy if the tables are dynamic.

Comment: thanks both will help. I saw somewhere , that transforming the td tags with appropriate xsl file may give me the resultant xml I want. So the key thing here is to get a surrounding tag along with the data. Can the | operator be used with a constant value to construct a delimetered result ? like <results>385.65,15:47:38</results>

Comment: I would suggest to use the XPath-Function `concat` for this - like this: `xpath='concat(//table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADE PRICE"]/td[2]/p, "," , //table[@class="projection"][2]//tr[td/p/text()="LAST TRADED TIME"]/td[5]/p'`

Comment: I had tried this but looks like xpath functions are not allowed in YQL , concat gave me error http://y.ahoo.it/mTASz

Comment: @SoulMan You *can* use xpath functions in a YQL statement, but it's a bit tricky to use. Try this: `SELECT * FROM html WHERE url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613551/combine-result-of-multiple-xpath-in-yql-queries' AND xpath='//*[@id="question-header"]/*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@itemprop), " "), " name ")]/descendant-or-self::*//text()'`

Comment: P.S. Stack Overflow has a strange bug where comment text can get altered, so the sample YQL statement won't work. Copy the raw data from this instead: http://pastebin.com/T5K3ZnVN